# @ngrx/store and Angular 5. How create property in store if not exist and subscribe to changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I have reducer whith action which can create new property in state.

app.module.ts

```
import { appReducers } from './app.reducers';

NgModule( {
    imports: [
    //.... standart modules
    StoreModule.forRoot( appReducers ),
```

app.reducers.ts

```
import * as fromGadgetReducer from './gadgets/gadget.reducer';

export interface State {
    gadgets:        fromGadgetReducer.State;
}

export const appReducers = {
    gadgets:        fromGadgetReducer.reducer,
};
```

gadget.reducer.ts

```
import * as gadgetActions from './gadget.actions';

export interface State {
    dummy: any;
}

const initialState: State = {
    dummy: ''
};

export function reducer( state = initialState, action: gadgetActions.AllTypes ): State {
    switch ( action.type ) {

        case gadgetActions.SET_PROPERTY:
            const newState = { ...state };
            newState[ action.propertyName ] = action.value;
            return newState;
    }
}
```

gadget.actions.ts

```
export const SET_PROPERTY       = '[ Gadget ] Set property';

export class SetProperty implements Action {
    readonly type = SET_PROPERTY;

    constructor( public propertyName: string, public value: any ) {
    }
}

export type AllTypes = SetProperty;
```

Now when i will call action from Angular5 component

```
this.store.dispatch( new SetProperty( 'newProp', 'value' ) );
```

state will looks like { dummy:'', newProp:'value' }.

My next step - subscribing to changes for that property. But here i have problem. When i subscribing from Angular 5 component, that property not exists in state.

```
@Component( {
     //standart stuff
} )
export class GadgetComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() propName: string = ;

    constructor( private store: Store<State>) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){

        this.store.dispatch( new SetProperty( this.propName, '' ) );

        this.store.select( state => state.gadgets[this.propName]).subscribe( value => {
            // Problem: value === undefined
            //do some action 
       });
    }
}
```

**My Question:** How i can check existing property in store, create if not exists and subscribe to that property? 
I try next, but it is not working:

```
this.store.select( state => state.gadgets.newProp ).take( 1 )
    .subscribe( state => {
        if ( typeof state === 'undefined' ) {
            // create property in state
            this.store.dispatch( new SetProperty( 'newProp', '' ) );
        }
        this.store.select(state => state.gadgets.newProp).subscribe( value => {
            // Problem: value === undefined
            //do some action 
        });
     } );
```

Comment: where is the `store` object?

Comment: in my particular case with angular5  store is in component class property.    constructor(
        private store: Store<State>
    ) {
 store; 
//or this.store;
}

Comment: can you add more information `State` class `reducerFactory` and so on

Comment: Added more information. Please tell if it's not clear and need more details.

Comment: Understanding your scenario more would help. What is your use-case for setting dynamic properties in state? What is the value in initializing the property to empty string rather than undefined? How many types of defaulted dynamic properties will you need to do. You could just do `.map(x => x == null ? '' : x).subscribe(...)` or filter it out (`.filter(x => x != null).subscribe(...)`) if you don't really want the value anyways.

Comment: My user-case: i get dynamicly generated gadgets and need make them communicate each other throught redux state. For that i dynamicly create property in redux state from one gadget and subscribe to that property other gadget. 

My problem that i subscribe to yet not existing property in state. That is why i'm gets undefined value in subscribe function. 
I want first check if this property initialized in store. If not initialized, add this property to store and after that subscribe to the property.

Comment: @Lumeniz OK, why is it a problem that the property doesn't exist on state?What benefit is `''` over `undefined`?

Comment: Thanks to all who helped. Now it's works. Not sure why, but it's works :)